# Is there an opposite to 'go to definition' in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can right click a variable/method/class etc and click 'go to definition' and it will show me where that variable/method/class was created.

Is there a way to do the opposite of that? Is there a way to see where that variable/method/class is used in your C# project?

Comment: You mean, "Find All References"?

Comment: exactly @LarsTech. Just answered my own question as you answered. Thankyou. Kept it on here in case other people needed help :)

Comment: Not only that, but there also is a way to get back : Ctrl+* allows you to get back, after having pressed F12

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right click, find all References. Or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

**UPDATE**

I know where the Ctrl+K+R vs Shift+F12 confusion stems from. For developers that set up their environment settings for C#, Visual Basic or JavaScript, Ctrl+K+R is the keyboard shortcut that shows up in context menus. Shift+F12 is the keyboard shortcut that shows up in context menus when the environment settings is set up for Web Development or General.

To change the environment settings:

Tools > Import and Export Settings > No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings > General / JavaScript / Visual Basic / Visual C# / Visual C++ / Visual F# / Web Development /Web Development (Code Only)

Comment: thanks :)) appreciate the short cut too. Very useful :)

Comment: I thought the short cut is Shift+ F12

Comment: @dustinmoris Yes, it has multiple shortcuts. I just got used to with Ctrl+K chords, it's more mnemonic http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/

Comment: That shortcut is not for 'Find All References' it is for  'Object Browser Go To Search Combo' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

Comment: Actually, the shortcuts vary considerably between versions and initial configuration choices.

Comment: ReSharper has a nice feature called 'Find Usages'.

Comment: I have a C# environment, and it has always been Shift+F12

Comment: Yes Shift+F12 is universal, it works on C# environment too, what's odd is Ctrl+K+R is what shows up as keyboard shortcut for Find All References in C# environment

Comment: @thisOneGuy Your right Resharper is not free. Its pretty popular so I thought it worth mentioning in case you had it.

Comment: yeah ive seen a lot of recommendations and a friend has used it before, looks very useful :)

Answer (score 8):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

It will find all references.